# DevExpress DateEdit String was not recognized as a valid DateTime | Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, datetime, devexpress

I've got a DevExpress `DateEdit` control (named `txtDoB`) on my form. I've been trying to poplualte it with a Date from the variable m._DateofBirth by doing this:

```
txtDoB.Text = Date.ParseExact(m._DateOfBirth, "dd/MM/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

But I receive the folowing error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

The variable is already set to Date format and the actual value is `15/02/1998`.

I've tried a number of different things, the `DateEdit` control hasn't been configured any differently than it's default configuration.

Any help would be appreciate as its getting frustrating.

Comment: `"dd/MM/yy"` versus `15/02/1998` notice any difference?  Keep in mind, you are using `ParseExact` - you are promising to specify the *exact* format for the date data .

Comment: I've already tried changing it to 'dd/MM/yyyy' but I still get the same error.

Comment: I think your code is also backwards - `ParseExact` returns a DateTime type but you are trying to store it in a text box (string).  otherwise, `"dd/MM/yyyy"` will work with the literal `"15/02/1998"` - check that `m._DateOfBirth` contains what you think it does and turn on Option Strict

Answer (score 0):

You must use [`DateEdit.EditValue`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsBaseEdit_EditValuetopic) instead of `DateEdit.Text`. And is better to break your code to two lines to determine where the error occurred:

```
parsedDate = Date.ParseExact(m._DateOfBirth, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
txtDoB.EditValue = parsedDate
```